# How can I make \pdfbookmark anchor on the page where a figure locates?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, bookmarks

I want to direct to a series of figures included in text. So I added something like

```
\pdfbookmark[1]{Figure 1}{fig:1}
```

But it goes to the same point it occurs in the source text, not the exact position of the figure.
Then I try to use `\pageref{fig:1}` and it works perfectly. But how can I hyperref it from the table of contents without using `\listoffigures`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hyperref,UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage[unicode={true}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\pdfbookmark[1]{Figure 1}{fig:1}
\pdfbookmark[1]{Figure 2}{fig:2}
\pdfbookmark[1]{Figure 3}{fig:3}
\pdfbookmark[1]{Figure 4}{fig:4}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\includegraphics{figure1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\includegraphics{figure2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\includegraphics{figure3}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\includegraphics{figure4}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a full example, not just fragments of code

Comment: Working means `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` since we don't have your figure files at hand ;-)

Comment: One sidenote: If you use bookmarks this way they will appear between bookmarks for chapters/sections etc. I don't know if this is really what you want to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bookmarks must be done where the figure appears, not on the first page, so add them separately to the figure environment.

A cleaner approach would be patching the `figure` environment to do this automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[unicode={true}]{hyperref}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[htbp]
\pdfbookmark[1]{Figure 1}{fig:1}
\includegraphics{figure1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\pdfbookmark[1]{Figure 2}{fig:2}
\includegraphics{figure2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\pdfbookmark[1]{Figure 3}{fig:3}
\includegraphics{figure3}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\pdfbookmark[1]{Figure 4}{fig:4}
\includegraphics{figure4}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

**Automated adding with a dummy ctr**

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage[draft,demo]{graphicx}


\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\usepackage[unicode={true}]{hyperref}

\newcounter{pdffigurectr}

\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{%
  \refstepcounter{pdffigurectr}%
  \pdfbookmark[1]{\figurename \number\value{pdffigurectr}}{fig:\number\value{pdffigurectr}}%
}

\begin{document}


\foreach \x in {1,...,20} {%
  \clearpage
  \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \includegraphics{figure\x}

    This is figure \x\ on page \thepage
  \end{figure}
}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your following up. That's exactly what I wanna achieve!